# How can I morph an image to appear "flat" when wrapped on a bottle?

Tags: line-art, distort

I want to create an image, say of an eye, and morph it so that when I print it it may not look clear/correct, but when I wrap it around a bottle and observe it at it's center point, it takes the shape of the eye again. I believe it's a similar affect to anamorphosis art done but when I search on that all I get is anamorphic art via a mirror image, so it's depending on reflective surfaces on the cylinder and that's not what I'm after, but simply an image that's only clear from a given angle.

I think it may be necessary to slice the image up and then distort each piece, but I'm not sure of how. I can do this in Photoshop so if there's a filter, that will be helpful.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I don't know that it is different for print than for others in terms of creation

Comment: I know this is done in 3D software. A image is projected onto a surface and then the surface is "rolled out" or flattened with the proejction baked into it. I thought it would be possible to simulate this with a gradient and the `displacement` filter in photoshop. Sadly I've not been getting good results with that approach.